# How to measure words per minute?

Tags: user-input

Been looking for a method to measure words per minute, with no luck. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean how quickly you can burst type in WPM, or how many words you've written per minute in the last hour, day, etc for a given document?

Comment: First one. It'd count the words I've written, until an idle timer stop counting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Making a command for this means:

1. Recording the time and number of words in the buffer at the start; you can use the `wordcount()` function to get the word count, and the `reltime()` function to get the time.
2. Subtracting the current time and number of words from the values we had at the start.
3. Profit!

Here is a basic function which does exactly that:

```
fun! s:wpm() abort
    " Start!
    if get(b:, 'wpm_start', 0) is 0
        let b:wpm_start = [reltime(), wordcount()]
    " Finish
    else
        let l:time = reltime(b:wpm_start[0])
        let l:words = wordcount()['words'] - b:wpm_start[1]['words']
        unlet b:wpm_start
        echom printf('%s WPM; in %s seconds you typed %s words',
            \ l:words / max([1, l:time[0] / 60]), l:time[0], l:words)
    endif
endfun

command! WPM call s:wpm()

" Optional: automatically do this when starting/leaving insert mode.
augroup wpm
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertEnter * :WPM
    autocmd InsertLeave * :WPM
augroup end
```

Comment: I think `reltimefloat()` would be more reliable.  The output format of `reltime()` is "system dependent."