# Measuring how much I write in vim by comparing word count on each save

Tags: vimscript

Suppose I want to write `N`  words related to my studies in Vim everyday as my daily goal.

Every time I am done writing something I can do `g`+`Ctrl-g` and then I can send that number variable to a file.  I want help in automating this.

If at each save vim can execute a shell command like `Words diff` (where `Words` is a bash script in my path) with `diff` being the word difference between the two saves, this can be automated.

The problem is that I don't know vim-script. With the basic structure of the function I think I will be able to tweak it to my needs.

Can you help?

#### Edit: full explanation

I imagine something like a `:Write` mode which sends the new added words (`diff`: difference between saves) on each save to a file.

Similar to this mode, I imagine an `:Edit` mode, which would do almost the same thing..  instead of sending the difference `diff`, it would send `2*abs(diff)`.

I use vim splits very often, so a full shell script solution which uses the only original file name can't solve my problem. For each split I would like to invoke these command functions separately.

I can do basic bash scripts, so you can leave the writing to file part to me.

Comment: This is also good. I am okay with bash. I was going to modify the vimscript function to make write and edit versions (as editing isn't really about adding words) but I guess I can also make two shell scripts. If I am editing a file, I would like to double the abs(wc difference). Anyway, please do put it as answer - your shell script is quite interesting.

Comment: If its a shell script though, I cannot switch between editing and writing without quitting. Also, writing with vim splits would not be possible. I think a vim function is needed.

Comment: I am sorry. I tried to keep it simple. I have edited my question.

Comment: No apology necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I modified [this answer by Martin Tournoij](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14635/how-to-measure-words-per-minute) to my needs.

```
fun! s:write() abort
     if get(b:, 'write_start', 0) is 0
        let b:write_start = wordcount()
     else
        let l:words = wordcount()['words'] - b:write_start['words']
        let b:write_start = wordcount()
        execute !BashScript l:words
     endif
endfun

command! Write call s:write()
```

where the BashScript is in the path and can be as simple as

```
#!/bin/bash
num=$1
echo $num >> path/to/your/file
```

Now I can call `:Write` at the beginning to initialize the word count and thereafter, on each `:Write` will append the added words to my file. This can of course be made fast using a custom `remap`.

It's trivial to repeat this for `:Edit` mode now.