# Constant-update Words Per Minute in Vim?

Tags: vimscript, original-vim

I'm interested (mostly just for fun) in seeing my typing speed while working in Vim. I saw [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14635/how-to-measure-words-per-minute) post but this requires starting and stopping a function. I would prefer this to be a constantly updating value in the bottom bar of Vim (similar to cursor position or something like that), perhaps taking and average of words written over the last 15 seconds and extrapolated to words per minute?

Not necessary, but if you could also provide some explanation of how your solution works that would be greatly appreciated! I'm still pretty new to the more interesting features of Vim and would love the opportunity to learn.

Thanks in advance!
Any hints in the right direction would also be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
This is a somewhat working version of what I want. I believe the main issue with this is that the time updates too frequently.

```
let g:last_word_count=[wordcount().words, reltimefloat(reltime())]
function WPM()
        if abs(reltimefloat(reltime()) - g:last_word_count[1]) > 0.5
                let g:timedif=abs(reltimefloat(reltime()) - g:last_word_count[1])
                let g:worddif=min([wordcount().words - g:last_word_count[0], 0])
                echom g:worddif
                let g:wpm=g:worddif / g:timedif * 60

                return string(g:wpm)
        endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This is an interesting question, but will likely take significant effort from someone to build, so don't hold your breath waiting for replies :)

Answer (score 0):

There is wpm plugin for neovim. But it is no longer mentioned by the owner. I think this would be a great starting point if you want to develop your own plugin.
https://github.com/jcdickinson/wpm.nvim

Comment: Thank you! I'll be sure to look into this and report back if i manage anything interesting